# Why my output not displaying what i want correctly

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculatePurchasePrice
{

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {


    Book Cost: $10.00
    State Tax Charged: $0.80
    County Tax Charged: $0.30
    Total Purchase Price: $11.10


    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Price of the book: ");

    bookPrice = kbd.nextDouble(); // get user input

    double staxCharged = bookPrice * stateTax;

    System.out.println("State Tax Charged: " + staxCharged);

    double ctaxCharged = bookPrice * countyTax;

    System.out.println("County Tax Charged: " + ctaxCharged);

    totalPP = bookPrice + staxCharged + ctaxCharged;

    System.out.println("Total Purchase Price: " + totalPP);

   }
}
```

Total is suppose to display $11.10
Total displays $11.1000000000001

Comment: It would be beneficial to explain in the body of the question what your question is again. Additionally, looking at this, what is going on after the declaration of your `main` method, with the prices listed? Is that supposed to be a comment?

Comment: yeah its a bit messy and i should have explained it better. It's my comments stating what i need it to display as well and what it is displaying with the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:  System.out.printf("Total Purchase Price: %.2f%n", totalPP);

You should read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: thank you! that fixed my program and I will give that a read right now.